# C# DataFlow: Wait for all tasks started by ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair to finish

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have a list of operations to be executed, and can be cancelled on user interaction. Pretty simple, but `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair .Completion` is never finishing. Here's an example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var taskSchedulerPair = new ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair();
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var optiions = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
    {
        TaskScheduler = taskSchedulerPair.ConcurrentScheduler,
        CancellationToken = cts.Token,
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5
    };
    var a1 = new ActionBlock<int>(new Func<int, Task<int>>(Moo), optiions);
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) a1.Post(i);
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to cancel...");
    Console.ReadKey(false);
    Console.WriteLine("Cancelling...");
    cts.Cancel();
    // taskSchedulerPair.Complete();
    taskSchedulerPair.Completion.Wait();
    // This never prints
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    Console.ReadKey(false);
}

public static async Task<int> Moo(int ms)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Starting: " + ms);
    await Task.Delay(4000);
    Console.WriteLine("Ending" + ms);
    return ms + 100;
}
```

Comment: Why use ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair ? In any case, it's the *action block* that needs to complete, not the scheduler. For normal termination you should call `a1.Complete();` and then `await a1.Completion;`.

Comment: If you followed [How to: Specify a Task Scheduler in a Dataflow Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-specify-a-task-scheduler-in-a-dataflow-block?view=netframework-4.7.2), it's only for illustration purposes and a somewhat unfortunate choice. There's no need to coordinate readers and writers with dataflow blocks that have input buffers. The block that uses `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` to update the UI is far more useful

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, can you write this as an answer? It solves my issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.concurrentexclusiveschedulerpair.complete?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Calling Complete is optional. **It is necessary only if you're relying on the Completion property for notification that all processing has been complete**.

So if you want to `Wait` on the `Completion` property then you have to call `Complete()` on the scheduler. This behavior is the same for a data flow block; to rely on the `Completion` property you have to call `Complete()` on the block.